# Create a VBA Loop to View Each Criteria in a Autofilter

Tags: excel, vba, loops, autofilter

I'll start by saying I have no idea if I'm even asking this question correctly...encouraging, huh?

I have an Excel spreadsheet, the first row of which are column headers with the autofilters activated. What I am trying to do is create a loop in VBA where the first individual criterion from the autofilter field:=2 is "checked" and the filtered data gets displayed; then "unchecked" and is undisplayed; and then the next below criterion in the filter box is "checked" and the filtered data gets displayed; then "unchecked" and undisplayed, and so on.

I do have other intentions on what to do with the data when it is displayed after the criteria is "checked" in the filter box, but I'm confident I can figure out the coding for those actions separately.

What I'm trying, or rather hoping, to avoid is creating a separate comma separated value range for what would be a massive array, since there are a lot of criterion in autofilter field:=2, and the those criteria in the autofilter field:=2 will occasionally change. Maybe that's possible, maybe it isn't.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE - I figured that it may be simpler to filter the unique values in column B and then paste those values in a distant spot, column S, on the worksheet. Then I recorded a basic filter macro and changed criteria1:= to cells(uic,19), the values in column S and created a do while loop to run the filter on the criteria in column S adding +1 before each loop.

The code is below -

```
 Sub filter_example()
 Dim lastrowuic, lastrowarray As Long
 lastrowuic = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
 lastrowarray = Cells(Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row
 Dim uniquesArray As Variant
 uniquesArray = Range("B2:B" & lastrowuic)
 Dim uic As Integer
 uic = 2

 With Sheet1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:B").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=.Range("S1"), Unique:=True
 End With

 Do While lastrowarray
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$21").AutoFilter=2,Criteria1:=Cells(uic, 19)
 ClearAllFilters = True
 uic = uic + 1
 Loop

 End Sub
```

The two areas that could afford cleaning up are the activesheet.range and really the end. This loop does do what I want, but I would like it to exit the loop once it gets to the first blank row, following the last row of data, in column "S" (aka 19) and then clear the filter in autofilter=2. That's really it. Otherwise this is doing what I want it to do.

Any additional assistance is appreciated!

Comment: You could use a dictionary to get all the unique values and then loop through its keys.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203910/how-do-i-loop-through-an-autofilter-using-vba-in-excel) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Not particularly. This is far more complex with the multiple sheets and copy and paste functions that what I'm trying to accomplish which is really no more than filter on a criteria in an autofilter field, display the data, then move "down" to the next criterion in the autofilter field.

Comment: Yes but it shows you an approach to take...

Comment: The linked question looks like it would meet your needs - just remove the parts you don't want (it's one line more than you asked for !)

Comment: Those suggestions were good inspirations. Basically what i did was filter out the uniques and copy and pasted them elsewhere on the sheet ("S1"), then I created a Do While loop using the criteria in column "S" as the autofilter=2 criteria and just adding one row to column "S" as the autofilter criteria.